# How do you get an object from a string in Objective C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

How can I get an object based from a string in Objective C?

For example

```
int carNumber=5;
[@"car%i",carNumber].speed=10;
//should be same as typing car5.speed=10;
```

Oh course, those are just made up objects, but how could I get an object based on what is in a variable.

Comment: I think you can consider to use NSArray or NSDictionary to store those numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot. When your code is compiled, the names of variables will no longer be what you've specified. `car5` is not and has never been a string.

The better strategy would be to have an array of car objects and then specify the index. In C style (where `carType` is the type of each car):

```
carType carArray[5];

//! (Initialize your cars)

int carNumber= 5;
carArray[carNumber].speed= 10;
```

In Objective-C, if your cars are objects:

```
NSMutableArray* carArray= [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

//! (Initialize your cars and add them to the array)

int carNumber= 5;
carType car= [carArray objectAtIndex:carNumber];
car.speed= 10;
```

Comment: This is possible with Key value coding: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html

Comment: It's possible if you make certain assumptions, such as that car5 is a property, but the OP's code looks more like it's an instance variable or a local variable. I tend to agree that an array is probably a better solution, Key-value coding might make it work but that doesn't make it the best solution.

Answer (score 4):

If you follow [Key-Value Coding](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html) then this is as easy as:

```
NSString *myValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"car%@", carNumber];
id myValue = [myClass valueForKey:myValue];
```

Comment: How exactly would I go about this? I get a redefinition of myValue error.

Comment: This was just pseudo code - you need to take these concepts and apply this to your situation.  First, you have to ensure you are following key-value coding.  If this is an iVar then you might not be able to do this.  Next, read the documentation around key value coding to see how to properly implement this (using this code as a guide).

Comment: This could be functioning code easily! Just rename `NSString *myValue` to `NSString *myKey`. And KVC works with ivars (assuming you don't have a method of the same name that it finds first).

Answer (score 0):

```
int carNumber = 5;
NSString *className = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"car%d", carNumber];
Class carClass = [[NSBundle mainBundle] classNamed:className];
if (carClass) {
    id car = [[carClass alloc] init];
    [car setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:10] forKey:@"speed"];
}
```

But there are issues such as saving try car class instance for later access, perhaps adding it to an `NSMutableArray`.

Answer (score -1):

Why not just store the car objects in an `NSArray`?

Comment: This is not an answer.  This should be a comment.

Comment: I was looking into this, but wasn't sure how.

Comment: Use the 'Add Comment' link above.

Comment: I meant I don't know how to use NSArrays with objects in the way I asked. Sorry for the confusion.